# GraphAutomorphismGroup bug or my misunderstanding?

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, permutation, group-theory, raspberry-pi

**Bug introduced in 10.3.1 or earlier and fixed in 11.2.0**

This bug was specific to the Raspberry Pi version.

---

I am using Mathematica 10.3.1.0 on a Raspberry Pi 3.
The following input:

```
k = Graph[{1, 2}, {UndirectedEdge[1, 2]}];
GraphAutomorphismGroup[k]
```

returns the output

```
PermutationGroup[{}]
```

Shouldn't it return instead, something like this ?

```
PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1,2}}]}]
```

Perhaps I have misunderstood, or perhaps the graph automorphism group function is not supported on the Raspberry Pi ?

Comment: Version 10.3.1 on Mac OS gives `PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2}}]}]`

Comment: Can you get any of the examples in [`GraphAutomorphismGroup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphAutomorphismGroup.html) to work?

Comment: You should report that to WRI support, regardless if others have reported it.

Comment: @JasonB I tried one of those, which also didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** This seems fixed in the latest RPi version, 11.2.0.

This is a bug specific to the Raspberry Pi (or rather ARM versions of Mathematica?).  I reported it on February 21, 2016, and Wolfram Support told me that it is a known issue.

A workaround is to use [the IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html), which provides the same functionality and works fine on the Raspberry Pi.

```
<<IGraphM`

IGBlissAutomorphismGroup[k]

(* {{2, 1}} *)
```

It returns a list of group generators, which you can use with `PermutationGroup` to construct a group.

Note: IGraph/M is very slow to load on the RPi. It may take a minute. Update: Since version 0.3, IGraph/M uses lazy loading and is much quicker to load on the Raspberry Pu.

Disclosure: I am the author of IGraph/M (but not of igraph).

Comment: Thank you very much Szabolcs ! You helped me a while ago with another graphs issue. I installed IGraph/M on the laptop I was using at the time but unfortunately was unable to use it because it wasn't compatible with version 9 of Mathematica. Now that I have an up-to-date version of Mathematica I am very much looking forward to trying IGraph/M !